# xmlhttp GET access website cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a chrome extension that needs to load all properties of a website by making an http get request. We're using `xmlhttprequest` for this. For most properties this is easy; for content we have `reponseText` and for headers we have `getAllResponseHeaders` but I can't seem to find a way to get all the **cookies**. I was wondering if others know a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get cross-origin cookies without injecting a content script into an open page - you can use [`chrome.cookies` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies).

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({url: "http://example.com/"}, function(cookies){/*...*/});
```

Note that you will need the `"cookies"` permission.